Two websites on iis with same configuration and application pool but one prompts Authorization window
I'm using a Node package (puppeteer) that launches Microsoft Edge behind the scenes.
When I use the package on one of the websites, it works fine, but when I use it with the other website it prompts this window in the server, and puppeteer won't work until I close this window (I don't even need to put credentials, just close it):

I've checked and both websites have the same configuration on IIS 10 and the same application pool.
Why?

Do they point to the same path, and are they running at the same time? If different paths, check the folder security permissions.

That's called basic auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication

Permissions are identical. I found out that the website that works fine uses LDAP to authenticate the users from the PHP side. The website that doesn't work uses username+password to login so I guess it sends some sort of authentication request to iis. Because when I changed the authentication method of this website to anonymous instead of Windows it worked. But Im afraid anonymous might leave security breaches?

note that you cannot login interactively as a domain user using username/password (you can use Integrated authentication though), so the other authentication types like basic will not use the domain as the credentials store. if you wish to write custom code you can use libraries like .net's system.web.security.membership to authenticate a user against a domain using username/password, but the stock IIS authentication types (other than Integrated Authentication) will not work.

@FrankThomas thank you, and since I am using PHP code and there aren't libraries that I know of that authenticate against the domain (I'm using Laravel's authentication methods), does it mean in my case that the best thing to do would be to leave it with Anonymous Authentication in IIS, and make sure the PHP auth is secure enough? Otherwise it would always prompt that Authorization window when I use certain scripts it seems?

@FrankThomas What I don't understand though is - why does it prompt this authorization window on the server? I thought that the entity handling requests is the application pool (MSA account in my case). And the MSA account has all permissions needed on the server. So doesn't it mean that when a user makes a request it goes through the MSA account which is already authorized? Or, because I specifically set Authentication to "Windows", it looks for the domain account credentials nonetheless?

does your site/virtual-application have a web.config file? As far as I'm aware, any app intended for running on a IIS apppool may have one, regardless of language, bur I;ve not run PHP on IIS.

Yes there is web.config (I think it's the same configuration from the "Configuration Editor" on the IIS GUI?) Is there a specific thing I should look for there? (Btw the web.config is identical on both sites, for the one that doesn't prompt the Authorization window as well, so still not sure why only this site prompts it)

Also it says "Authorization" and not "Authentication" which is also confusing to me (Or it's the same thing in this case?)

@FrankThomas, There is actually 1 big difference between the working site and the one that doesn't (with the Windows Authentication) - the site that works, uses a PHP LDAP package, so maybe the LDAP packge handles the authentication somehow together with IIS (as opposed to the username+password combination on the site that makes the Authorization window prompt)

so on the topic of Authorization vs Authentication, IIS decides whether a user needs to authenticate when the resource in question requires authorization. for instance if you have an application root web.config that contains <authorization> elements that aren't allow users="*" the site will then require authentication to see if the user has the authorization to access the resource in question. Either way, I'm assuming you want users to be able to authenticate with domain identities correct?
